# GoBack() seems to be passing parameter in OnNavigatedFrom but it shouldn't, why?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have an UWP app which has two pages `HomePage` and `EditItemPage`. On `HomePage` I created a button which navigates to `EditItemPage` passing class `NavigationContext` which `bool isNewItem = true`. Then, I create new Item on `EditItemPage`, user changes some info and clicks button `Save`. That button passes that created `Item` in `NavigationContext` to `HomePage`. The problem is when I click on back button without clicking `Save` button my `HomePage` somehow get that item.

**EditItemPage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class EditItemPage : Page
{
    public EditItemPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        ViewModel.CleanNavigationBackStack.Execute(e.Uri);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (e.Parameter is NavigationContext)
        {
            var context = (NavigationContext) e.Parameter;
            if (context.ContextType == NavigationContextType.ShareOperation)
            {
                ViewModel.HandleNewUri.Execute(context.ShareOperation);
            }
            else if (context.ContextType == NavigationContextType.FeedItem)
            {
                if (context.IsNewItem)
                    ViewModel.HandleNewFeedItem();
                else
                {
                    ViewModel.HandleExistingFeedItem(context.FeedItem);
                }
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private EditItemViewModel ViewModel => this.DataContext as EditItemViewModel;
}
```

**HomePage.xaml.cs**

```
public sealed partial class HomePage : Page
{
    public HomePage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        if (e.Parameter is NavigationContext)
        {
            var context = (NavigationContext) e.Parameter;
            if (context.ContextType == NavigationContextType.FeedItem)
            {
                if (context.IsNewItem)
                    ViewModel.HandleNewFeedItem(context.FeedItem);
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private FeedViewModel ViewModel => this.DataContext as FeedViewModel;
}
```

**NavigationService**:

```
public class NavigationService : INavigationService
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Type> _pagesDictionary;
    private Frame _mainFrame;

    public const string UnknownPageKey = "-- UNKNOWN --";

    public NavigationService()
    {
        _pagesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    }

    public void Configure(string key, Type pageType)
    {
        if (key == null || pageType == null) return;
        Type value;
        if (_pagesDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            if (value != pageType)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                    $"Attempt to add a page of type '{pageType}' to already existing pair of '{key}:{value}'. Consider another string.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _pagesDictionary.Add(key, pageType);
        }
    }


    public void GoBack()
    {
        if (EnsureMainFrame() && _mainFrame.CanGoBack)
            _mainFrame.GoBack();
    }

    public void NavigateTo(string pageKey)
    {
        if (pageKey == null) return;
        Type page;
        if (_pagesDictionary.TryGetValue(pageKey, out page))
        {
            if (EnsureMainFrame())
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                    AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
                _mainFrame.Navigate(page, null,
                    new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"There is no page associated with string '{pageKey}'.");
        }
    }

    public void NavigateTo(string pageKey, NavigationContext context)
    {
        if (pageKey == null) return;
        Type page;
        if (_pagesDictionary.TryGetValue(pageKey, out page))
        {
            if (EnsureMainFrame())
            {
                SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility =
                    AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
                _mainFrame.Navigate(page, context,
                    new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.SuppressNavigationTransitionInfo());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception($"There is no page associated with string '{pageKey}'.");
        }
    }

    private bool EnsureMainFrame()
    {
        if (_mainFrame != null) return true;
        var appShell = Window.Current.Content as AppShell;
        if (appShell != null) _mainFrame = appShell.AppFrame;
        return _mainFrame != null;
    }

    public string CurrentPageKey
    {
        get
        {
            string key;
            try
            {
                key = _pagesDictionary.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == _mainFrame.CurrentSourcePageType).Key;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException)
            {
                return UnknownPageKey;
            }
            return key;
        }
    }

    public void RemoveLast()
    {
        if (EnsureMainFrame() && _mainFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            _mainFrame.BackStack.RemoveAt(_mainFrame.BackStackDepth - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I've read that `GoBack()` doesn't pass any argument but when I click it method `OnNavigatedFrom` somehow get that old `NavigationContext`. Tell me when I make a mistake :)

Comment: We're missing some important pieces to correctly answer your question. Like where you set the FeedItem property

Comment: The issue really could be anywhere in the code you haven't included. Can you provide a complete, minimal reproduction of the issue?